# Cannot deserialize protobuf binary (created by Nodejs) in Python

Tags: python, node.js, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers

Please review below context and help resolve the issue

I define below message in device.proto

```
message DeviceConfiguration {
  message Resolution {
    uint32 width = 1;
    uint32 height = 2;
  }
  string device_name = 1;
  string brand_name = 2;
  Resolution resolution = 3;
}
```

Then, compile this message into 2 languages: Nodejs (device_pb.js) and Python(device_pb2.py)

**1. From Nodejs: send above message to Kafka**

```
const {DeviceConfiguration} = require("./device_pb")

const resolution = new DeviceConfiguration.Resolution();
resolution.setWidth(1280);
resolution.setHeight(960);

const deviceConfiguration = new DeviceConfiguration();
deviceConfiguration.setDeviceName("S6");
deviceConfiguration.setBrandName("samsung");
deviceConfiguration.setResolution(resolution);

let binaryEvent = deviceConfiguration.serializeBinary();
```

Finally, use Kafka-node to send **binaryEvent** value to a Kafka topic

**2. From Python component: consume the message via kafka**

- Here is binary value received in python component

> b'10,8,111,98,106,101,99,116,73,100,26,21,10,2,83,54,18,7,115,97,109,115,117,110,103,26,6,8,128,10,16,192,7'

- Then, I use below code to deserialize the message but it throws a message **"Error parsing message"**

  from device_pb2 import DeviceConfiguration

  device = DeviceConfiguration()

  device.ParseFromString(message)

=> As I see that the **ParseFromString** doesn't work for above binary value and throws "Error parsing message". It only works if the bytes value is created by **SerializeToString** python code.

Note that: I'm able to deserialize the binary by using **deserializeBinary** (make it public) in Nodejs but there is **no similar function** in device_pb2.py

So, **is there any way for me to deserialize the message in Python code?**

Many Thanks.

Comment: I see the "samsung" in the binary value: `[ord(c) for c in "samsung"] => [115, 97, 109, 115, 117, 110, 103]`.

But overall the payload strikes me as too large.  The other fields in the proto should take maybe 10 additional bytes? I would guess that there is extraneous data. Can you try transmitting a simpler, non-proto payload such as "abc" from Node and see what comes out on the Python side?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @GregKrimer . I have not tried with non-proto payload yet. I think it will work if we go with normal text. In our project, we need a python consumer to consume proto payload from Nodejs. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm not suggesting that you change your project to not use protos. I am only suggesting that you run a test using a simpler plain text payload for debugging purposes. My suspicion is that there is data corruption somewhere in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @GregKrimer. I tried a simple text and the result is similar. I got below message when using ParseFromString - RuntimeWarning: Unexpected end-group tag: Not all data was converted

Comment: Don't call ParseFromString on a non-proto payload. Just print the bytes as you have with the binary value received in the Python component above and compare it to the value sent. What was the simple text that you sent btw?

Comment: Sorry for answering late @GregKrimer. I resolved the issue. The solution is we need to do a small step to convert the above data to bytes in value_deserializer before calling ParseFromString. Here is my solution

def to_binary_string(x):
    x = x.decode('utf-8').split(',')
    return bytes(list(map(lambda i: int(i), x)))